# Adobe air (HTML+JS) prevent rightClick event of image, input and textarea

Tags: air, adobe

I'm working on an Adobe Air application. It's base on html and js. So there are `img`, `input` and `textarea` tags, which will show a native menu when right-click. For example, right click on the `img` tag, It shows a native menu with **save image** menu-item.

I've tried using normal javascript methods, like `event.preventDefault()`, and It doesn't work at all.

So how to prevent those native menus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it very easy to solve this problem after 7 months. It's something about `contextmenu`.

### Example:

Here is an `<img>` now.

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png">
```

Add a `contextmenu` event listener for it, and prevent its default bebaviour.

```
<img id="a" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" >

<script>
  $('#a').on('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
</script>
```

Then the default menu disappears.

### Demo [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Witcher42/VQWF7/)